# Rounded Corner For CGRectAddArc

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgrect

The below code draws the rounded corner at the at the end of the path(green color). But, not at the start. What could be done so that I have the rounded corner at the start too(where Red colour starts). Its not perfect round at the start.

[image]

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{


     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGFloat arcStartAngle = M_PI;
    CGFloat arcEndAngle = 2 * M_PI;

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(0,CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect),CGRectGetMidY(rect));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGFloat colors[] =
    {
        1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,  
        0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0
    };

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, colors, NULL, 2);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);



    CGMutablePathRef arc = CGPathCreateMutable();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(arc, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);


    CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGFloat radius = CGRectGetMidX(rect);

    CGPathAddArc(arc, NULL, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, radius-5.0,
                 arcStartAngle, arcEndAngle, NO);



    CGPathRef strokedArc = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(arc, NULL, 10.0f,
                                                          kCGLineCapRound, kCGLineJoinRound, 10.0f);


    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGContextAddPath(context, strokedArc);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);


}
```

Comment: There are no corners in your drawing, rounded or not. Could you be more specific about what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I had been working on your question and this is what I have found.
Your problem is related to your begin path point you have

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(arc, NULL, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
```

but for your example you need start on startPoint.x + 5 because you are using 10 of width of your path so you need modify this line and use this instead

```
CGPathMoveToPoint(arc, NULL, startPoint.x + 5, startPoint.y);
```

and now should work, This is the result

[image]

I hope this helps you.